# COM MFC ATL worth studying?

Tags: com, mfc, atl

Is it worth studying COM MFC ATL WTL now?

Comment: we use COM and ATL here on a daily basis, and it's not ready to change (Ms Office ftw)

Comment: IMHO its possible to use COM without understanding much about it:-), Visual Studio will do all the boilerplate stuff & more based on your input to the wizard. The first chapters of Don Box's book "Essential COM" are worth reading, as he explains COM was developed to fulfil a need for drop-in components, & shows how a C++ library can be developed which has a consistent, unvarying binary interface, so that library updates do not require recompilation of the entire application, i.e. a COM dynamic linked library. His book certainly shed a lot of light upon the subject for me.

Answer (score 6):

Everything is worth studying:

*Those who forget history are doomed to repeat it*

*You must understand the past to understand the present*

Should you spend a majority of your time on it?  Only if you expect that you will have to work with it.  Otherwise, focus on the future.

Comment: -1: Doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: +one Pretty great advice. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Potentially yes for COM and ATL, if you're planning to program for Windows 7.  All the new platform APIs coming out are COM-based: Direct 2d, Ribbon, Animation, Location & Sensors, Libraries, etc...

There will likely be .NET wrappers for some of these, but managed code is no longer the focus for the Windows team, at least for now and the near future.

Answer (score 2):

The concepts of COM are really worth understanding. Especially the concept of interfaces, object creation strategies, proxies and Apartments.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  If you want to make a COM object now, you could just use C++/.NET instead.  If you want a UI, WinForms or WPF work fine.

Comment: COM was _always_ language neutral !!!

Comment: SharePoint 2010 requires IFilter (COM) implementations to be written in C++; or at the very least, unmanaged code -- COM in assembler anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you might get a job at Microsoft in their second most profitable business, Office, which is still based on COM.  There are worse fates than that.

Comment: Most M$ technologies use COM as their basis.  Why?  because it's a _damn_ good technology!  It's only problem is that it's poorly documented.  But while the OS, DirectX, DirectShow, Media Foundation, Office products etc continue to use COM as their foundation, COM will be an invaluable technology to have under your belt.

Answer (score 1):

COM is totally worth it.  The rest, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have to interface with some COM objects OR if you have to maintain some old COM/ATL code.

Same goes for MFC/WTL. Better and quicker UIs can be developed with latest .NET tools such as WPF and Winforms.

Comment: There are plenty of non-legacy COM objects that continue to be released in the worlds of Windows and Office.

Comment: Yes, you are right... I should remove the word 'legacy'